# Repeating pattern for a regex -- validate the same

Tags: regex

The url of my username is:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/12283851/user12283851
```

For this username it looks like the regular expression might be close to:

```
r'https?://stackoverflow.com/users/\d{1,9}/user\d{1,9}'
```

Is there a way in the regex to make sure that the first ID matches the second? In other words:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/12283851/user12283851 <== Valid
https://stackoverflow.com/users/11111111/user12283851 <== Invalid
```

Comment: You could use a backreference `https?://stackoverflow\.com/users/(\d{1,9})/user\1` See https://regex101.com/r/PWGEDN/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is accomplished by using [backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html).

> The backreference \1 (backslash one) references the first capturing group. \1 matches the exact same text that was matched by the first capturing group

In your example the following regex would work:

`https?://stackoverflow\.com/users/(\d{1,9})/user\1`

See this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/E7wSDb/4)

Comment: You don't have to escape the backslashes.

Comment: You are right, I updated the answer. I was used to escape the backslashes because  it is the default delimeter on regex101. Thanks!